# What is the logic behind django password encryption

Tags: python, django, authentication, encryption, sha

I need to make mobile app using  sencha as client  and  django as server

I am sending request as follows to server

```
url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/?format=jsonp',
                method: 'GET',
        headers : {'Authorization' : CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("password", "1154590211545902"),'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'
         }
```

I need to query **request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')** with the password in the database.

**request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')** return encrypted value for the password like  ea121221rtrtrt7878237878787  which is irreversible

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Django authentication module doesn't store the password in the database as a plain text.
- rather it apply hashing algorithms like 'SHA1' on the password and stores it (as a hash value).
- From the hash value you can't get the password as plain text.
- You can apply the same hashing algorithm on the given password and check against the stored password.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the built-in authentication framework, this is fully documented: [Manually checking a user's password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#manually-checking-a-user-s-password).